# How to only show server directory list to a certain user in PHP?

Tags: php

I just finally after trying many time over the past few years, got my dev serer online.  I put it online so I can show a couple friends progress on my work so I am not that worried about security because only a couple people will know the URL.

One thing I would like to accomplish though it to have the default directory list hidden, I know that is easy in an .htaccess file but I would like to somehow still show the directory lists to me, it could use some sort of login or based on my home IP, I just need a simple way, any suggestions on how I can do this?

I know I can make a simple PHP script but I would need to drop it into every directory almost and I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a separate `<VirtualHost>` that contains:

```
Deny from all
Allow from <your IP address here>
Options +Indexes
```

Comment: I try adding this to my conf file with my other virtualhost settings and when I do, I am unable to get apache to start, if I remove it again then apache will bott up fine, any ideas?   

<VirtualHost localhost:80>
Deny from all
Allow from MY-IP-HERE
Options +Indexes
</VirtualHost>